# Separate specifications for p and n in a binomial GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

For a binomial GLM, both the probability and the number of trials are important for each data entry. Using the `glm` fucntion in R, how do I specify them separately and explicitly?

Previously, when using `glm` for the binomial family, I used `glm(cbind(V4, V5) ~ V1 + V2 + V3, family=binomial)` where V4 is the number of success and V5 is the number of failures. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways to do binomial glms; you mention one (we'll call that the first way).

There's also a third way I'll cover at the end, which by the sound of it is perhaps what you're after.

---

**The second way**

This is clearly described in the help on GLMs (`?glm`), which is to supply the outcome for each individual bernoulli (0-1) trial. The help says:

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures.

(The last part in that quote describes your first way; the first two-thirds describes the way I am discussing now.)

That is, if you give it a factor as your response, it will be interpreted as a 0-1 variable, where the first level of the factor is "0" or "Failure" and all other levels count as "1" or "Success". If you supply such a factor (or a 1-column variable that can be coerced to one) R then "knows" there's a column of 1's for the $n$, so you don't need to specify that.

Here's some sample code to generate some data and run it:

```
x=c(9:20,5:25)
p=1/(1+exp(-(-7.5+.5*x)))
y=rbinom(x,1,p)
head(y,12)
plot(x,y)
points(x,p,pch=".",cex=4,col=4)
summary(glm(y~x,family=binomial))
points(x,fitted(glm(y~x,family=binomial)),col=3,cex=0.7)
```

Note that `y` was numeric (0-1) not a factor but since only one column was supplied it should be coerced to a factor by R; that is, supplying a numeric 0-1 variable works as-is.

Here's the plot the above code produces for my random numbers (if you run the code you'll get different numbers, of course). The black circles are the 0-1 outcomes, $y$, against the independent variable, $x$, while the blue dots are the population $p$'s from which the $y$s were randomly generated. The green circles are the fitted values from the model.

[image: binomial glm plot]

If you want my particular y, here's a copy:

```
y <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
```

---

**The third way**

(This way is the way to do the sample $p$ and $n$ 'separately and explicitly'.)

You can supply sample $p$'s and $n$'s, by giving the $p$'s as the response and the $n$'s as weights:

```
 x <- c(12,15,16,18,20)
 num.tr <- c(8,10,7,14,6)
 num.s <- c(2,3,3,9,5)
 prop.s <- num.s/num.tr
 glm( prop.s ~ x, weight=num.tr, family=binomial)
```

Compare that with the "usual" way:

```
 glm( cbind(num.s, num.tr - num.s ) ~ x, family=binomial)
```